# Column count doesn't match

Tags: mysql

Trying to insert some information into a table, I am getting the following error "Column count doesn't value at row1" This error seems clear but as far as I can tell the information is correctly entered.

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Thanks in advance!!!!!

```
create table patient(
  patientno Int(6) unsigned zerofill auto_increment, -- see Numbers.sql next week
  title ENUM ('Mr.', 'Mrs.', 'Miss.', 'Ms.','Dr.','Fr.','Rev.'), --  constraint on values entered into the column, default value is first element in list, if wrong data entered MySQL truncates the illegal value to  ' ' (an empty string).
  pname varchar(45) not null default 'Smith',
  degree SET ('B Sc','B Eng','B Comm','M Sc','Phd') not null ,
  job ENUM ('CLERK','SALESMAN','MANAGER','ANALYST','PRESIDENT'),
  assignedentist smallint unsigned,
  currency_symbol varchar(10),
  salary DECIMAL(6,2) unsigned,# 6 is the total number of digits and 2 is the number of digits after the decimal point, values that can be stored in the salary column range from -9999.99 to 9999.99
  comm DECIMAL(6,2) unsigned, # values that can be stored in the comm column range from -9999.99 to 9999.99
  appno TINYINT unsigned not null default 20,
  last_update  TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  picture LONGBLOB DEFAULT NULL,           # Picture in DATABASE as BLOB (up to 4.2GB)
  picture_path varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,   # Path to where picture is stored in file system,
  primary key (patientno)
)  Engine=InnoDB;



INSERT INTO patient (patientno, title, pname, degree, job, assignedentist, currency_symbol, salary, comm, appno,picture,picture_path) VALUES
(7369, 'Miss.','SMITH', ('B Sc,M Sc,Phd'),'Developer', 7566, '2010-12-17', 0xE282AC,800.23, NULL, 20,load_file('c:/teeth/teeth1.jpg'),'/teeth1.jpg'),
(7499, 'Mr.','ALLEN', ('B Eng,Phd'),'SALESMAN', 7698, '2011-02-20',0xE282AC, 1600.56, 300.23, 30, load_file('c:/teeth/teeth2.jpg'),'/teeth2.jpg'),
(7521, 'Mr.','WARD', ('B Eng,B Comm'),'Self Employed', 7566, '2011-02-22',0xE282AC, 1250, 500, 30,load_file('c:/teeth/teeth3.png'),'/teeth3.png'),
(7566, 'Rev.','JONES', ('B Sc,M Sc,Phd'),'Lecturer', 7839, '2011-04-02',0xE282AC, 2976, NULL, 20, load_file('c:/teeth/teeth4.jpg'),'/teeth4.jpg'),
(7654, 'Fr.','MARTIN', ('B Comm,Phd'),'SALESMAN', 7698, '2011-09-28',0xE282AC, 1250, 1400, 30,load_file('c:/teeth/teeth5.jpg'),'/teeth5.jpg'),
(7698, 'Mr.','BLAKE', ('B Sc,B Eng,B Comm,M Sc,Phd'),'MANAGER', 7839, '2011-01-05', 0xE282AC,2850, NULL, 30, load_file('c:/teeth/teeth6.png'),'/teeth6.png'),
(7782, 'Mr.','CLARK', ('B Comm,Phd'),'MANAGER', 7839, '2011-09-06',0xE282AC, 2450, NULL, 10, load_file('c:/teeth/teeth7.jpg'),'/teeth7.jpg'),
(7788, 'Mr.','SCOTT', ('B Comm,Phd'),'Army', 7788, '2012-12-09',0xE282AC, 3000, NULL, 20, load_file('c:/teeth/teeth8.jpg'),'/teeth8.jpg'),
(7839, 'Miss.','KING',('B Comm'), 'PRESIDENT', NULL, '2011-11-17',0xE282AC, NULL, NULL, 10, load_file('c:/teeth/teeth9.jpg'),'/teeth9.jpg'),
(7844, 'Mr.','TURNER', ('B Comm,Phd'),'UX', 7698, '2011-09-08', 0xE282AC,1500, 0, 30, load_file('c:/teeth/teeth10.jpg'),'/teeth10.jpg'),
(7876, 'Mrs.','ADAMS',('B SC,M Sc') ,'Database Desinger', 7788, '2013-12-01',0xE282AC, 1100, NULL, 20, load_file('c:/teeth/teeth1.jpg'),'/teeth1.jpg'),
(7900, 'Mr.','JAMES', ('B Comm,Phd'),'CLERK', 7698, '2011-12-03', 0xE282AC,950, NULL, 30, load_file('c:/teeth/teeth2.jpg'),'/teeth2.jpg'),
(7902, 'Mrs.','FORD', ('B Comm,M Sc,Phd'),'Data ANALYST', 7902, '2011-12-01', 0xE282AC,3000, NULL, 20,load_file('c:/teeth/teeth4.jpg'),'/teeth4.jpg'),
(7934, 'Mr.','MILLER',('B SC,M Sc') ,'CLERK', 7782, '2012-06-23',0xE282AC, 1300, NULL, 10, load_file('c:/teeth/teeth8.jpg'),'/teeth8.jpg');
```

Comment: For the degree values, you are inserting `('B Sc,M Sc,Phd')` ... what is this supposed to be doing?

Comment: It's just information about that persons education - phd bsc, Masters

Comment: This is not valid MySQL syntax. You can't insert a tuple within a tuple.  You should avoid storing CSV data in your table.

Comment: Thanks, I will try take this out and try again.

Comment: Thanks for the tip I'll keep it in mind, Unfortunately I am getting the same output.

Answer (score 1):

Your INSERT statement names 12 columns, but in the VALUES you have 13 values.

You must have the same number of values as the number of columns.

Also I'm not sure how the value '2010-12-17' is a good value for `currency_symbol`.

I think you need to just double-check every column to value pairing in your INSERT statement. It looks fishy.